# Directly Set Column of BelongsTo Association in Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

Say I have the following AR Object:

```
namespace Models
{
    [ActiveRecord(Lazy = true, Table = "Answer"), Serializable]
    public class Answer : ActiveRecordLinqBase<Answer>
    {
        public Answer() {}

        [PrimaryKey]
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }

        [BelongsTo("QuestionID")]
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there any way for me to directly set QuestionID?  I tried creating an additional AR [Property] called QuestionID for this purpose, but I run into the NH error described here:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/03/19/nhibernate-and-invalid-index-n-for-this-sqlparametercollection-with-count-n-error.aspx

I am trying to unit test this class, and I *really* don't want to have to set up a database (in memory or otherwise) to do this unit testing.  Setting the QuestionID is all I need to do for the functionality currently under test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack that accomplishes what I need, but negatively impacts the NH cache (I think): I simply assign to a "new" Question, instantiated with the *existing* question's ID.  It looks horrible, and, like I said, it essentially loads the cache with these (very) partially-filled question objects (not verified, but behavior seems to indicate as much).